# Problema con pase de variables entre funciones y manipulacion de strings

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema, me mandaron a practicar el ingreso de cadenas con las funciones `strcat()` y `memset()` por medio del uso de funciones, la situación es que cuando se realiza la operación de dicha función se queda guardado el cambio y se ejecuta en la otra función, es decir, en la primera función transformo todos los caracteres en `*` y al momento de realizar la segunda función lo hace con el cambio anterior quedando por ejemplo `"hola****"` y debería ser `"holamundo"`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <cerrno>
using namespace std;
char palabra1[50], palabra2[50];
void pedirDatos(char[], char[]);
void datos(char[], char[]);
void sobreescribir(char[]);
void anadirc(char [], char []);
int op, sw = 0;
int main()
{
    pedirDatos(palabra1, palabra2);
    datos(palabra1, palabra2);
    do
    {
        system ("cls");
        cout << " OPCIONES CON FUNCIONES STRING" << endl;
        cout << " \t 1.(memset)sobreescribir con '*' sobre la primera cadena" << endl;
        cout << " \t 2.(strcat)añadir una cadena al final de otra" << endl;
        cout << " \t 3. Salir" << endl;
        cout << "Ingrese su opcion ==>> ";
        cin >> op;
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                datos(palabra1,palabra2);
                sobreescribir(palabra1);
                break;
            case 2:
                datos(palabra1,palabra2);
                anadirc(palabra1,palabra2);
                break;
            case 3:
                sw=1;
                break;
            default : 
                cout << "Opcion no existe...." << endl;
        }
    }while (sw == 0);
}
void sobreescribir(char palabra1[])
{

    int n;
    cout << "ingrese desde que caracter desea el cambio: ";
    cin >>n;
    void *asterisco = memset(palabra1,'*', n);
    cout << palabra1 << endl;
    getch();
}
void anadirc(char palabra1[], char palabra2[])
{
    char *d= strcat(palabra2, palabra1);
    cout << "la cadena 1 se pone al final de la cadena 2 dando ---> " << palabra2 << endl;
    system("pause");

    getch();
    return ;
}
void pedirDatos( char palabra1[], char palabra2[])
{
    fflush(stdin);
    cout << "Ingrese la primera cadena de caracteres: ";
    cin.getline(palabra1, 50, '\n');
    cout << "Ingrese la segunda cadena de caracteres: ";
    cin.getline(palabra2, 50, '\n');
    
}
void datos(char palabra1[], char palabra2[])
{
    palabra1;
    palabra2;
}
```

Comment: Allí no veo algunas librerías, como: __#include <stdio.h>__, o bien, __#include <stdlib.h>__

Comment: @DamianGarcia teniendo en cuenta que es c++ y no C, es normal, lo esperable sería encontrar `#include <iostream>` y cosas así

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer la función `datos`? ¿Qué caso de uso te falla? ¿Por qué llamas a `pedirDatos` al inicio del programa, antes del bucle?

Comment: "*Tengo un problema, me mandaron a practicar el ingreso de cadenas con las funciones `strcat()` y `memset()`*" Ciertamente es un problema, si te mandaron practicar esas funciones mientras te enseñaban [tag:c++] el problema es que estás perdiendo el tiempo.